# How do we in Windows 10 not prompt for password when login

Tags: windows, windows-10

How do we in Windows 10 not prompt for password when login or in other words ( remove login password )

What I'd like to acocmplish is to not have to enter a password for Windows 10 at all just start up to desktop. I've tried to alter setting under account settings --> sign in options but no luck

Comment: Have you set the default user?  How you do that is exactly the same way.  I have an answer that goes into detail.  Have you tried setting the default user?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

First, if you are using a Windows Live account, you can consider converting it to a normal account, and then try the following:

If you are using a normal account (or converted your windows live account to normal) and there are no other accounts on the computer, if you change the password to nothing, it will no longer ask for a password but sign you in automatically. This does not work if your pc is joined to a Domain however.

If you really want to use a password on your computer (for example, its a requirement for password protected shares and to use Remote Desktop to connect to your pc from an external source) you can use `netplwiz` to automatically log into your computer by entering your username and password. (believe it or not, this tool is already on your computer, just search for it in the start menu.) This however does not work either if you are joined to a Domain, because then the checkbox required to activate it is gone.

It is possible to download software that will make it work in a domain or use a registry tweak and manually add the information to enable automatic login. I doubt you need to go this deep and it has been posted quite a few times before on SuperUser, so I'm sure you can do without that info in this post.

The netplwiz option also works for live accounts, you just have to figure out what your username is, as I think its not the full email addres.